# How can I return the attributes for all class in the inheritance chain?

Tags: python

If you have a class hierarchy and some class attribute is overridden in child class then the user of child class should not care what was the value of this attribute in parent classes.

But this is what I want to achieve:

```
class A:
    _ITEM = "A"

    @classmethod
    def getClassPath(cls):
        ???


class B(A):
    _ITEM = "B"


class C(B):
    _ITEM = "C"


# expected behavior:
A.getClassPath()  # "/A"
B.getClassPath()  # "/A/B"
C.getClassPath()  # "/A/B/C"
```

My original problem is a little more complicated, but it is reduced to this: get `_ITEM` attributes from all the classes in hierarchy and combine them somehow.

How can I do it? There is no multiple inheritance in my case.

Comment: i believe what you want to achieve can be done using the method resolution order (mro).
By manipulate the list it gives you, you could build the path that you want

Comment: Yeah it's easier to just take the parent method and append to it.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve by having the `getClassPath` method?

Comment: @venky__ It's not that simple. The rules how to combine elements are not changed, so I want my method to be implemented only in one class (base class of my hierarchy). There is no "parent method" in this case!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `mro` (method resolution order) to access attributes in the inheritance chain.  The simple case:

```
class A:
    _ITEM = "A"
    
    @classmethod
    def get_class_path(cls):
        result = cls.mro()[:-1]
        result = [res._ITEM for res in reversed(result)]
        result = "/" + "/".join(result)
        return result
```

If, additionally, you want to skip classes that don't have `_ITEM`, you can modify slightly with `vars()`:

```
class A:
    _ITEM = "attr_A"

    @classmethod
    def get_class_path(cls):
        mro_list = reversed(cls.mro()[:-1])

        result = []
        for obj in mro_list:
            if "_ITEM" in vars(obj):
                result.append(obj._ITEM)

        result = "/" + "/".join(result)
        return result

class B(A):
    # _ITEM = "attr_B"
    pass

class C(B):
    _ITEM = "attr_C"
```

output:

```
B.get_class_path() # returns '/attr_A'
C.get_class_path() # returns '/attr_A/attr_C'
```

Comment: Thanks, I see. Your implementation of `get_class_path` method does not take values of `_ITEM` attribute, you use the name of class. In my question the value of `_ITEM` attribute is the same as class name - but this is just a coinsidence!

Comment: I see.  You really want to return something like `f"{A._ITEM}/{B._ITEM}"` then?

Comment: Yes! And one more thing: the value may be not declared in some classes. F.e. if the value is not overridden in `class B` the expected result for `C.get_class_path()` should be "/A/C", not "/A/A/C".

Comment: I guess I can detect 'doubled' items using `is` check. Is there a better approach?

Comment: @lesnik updated, I think this should work for you